При компиляции в VisualStudio солюшина не билдится проект из-за ошибки отсутствия локализованой сборки с локализованіми ресурсами
Не могу понять в чем дело. Раньше так делал и небыло никаких проблем, но сейчас почему-то не получается.
Суть в том, что добавил в проект ресурсный файл со строками, а так же его локализованые версии. Типа сначала добавил Strings.resx, в котором находятся строковые значения на английском, Студия сгенерировала для него класс-дизанер, и так же добавил его локализованую версию Strings.ru.resx, но уже без класса, с русскими значениями строк. Но проект почему-то не компилируется - ошибка MSB3030, пишет, что не находит локализованую версию, ресурсную dll, в подпапке ru, и этой папки и файла действительно почему-то нет, почему-то Студия не собирает эту сборку.
Почему так? Ведь раньше все прекрасно работало!
Вот текст ошибки:

MSB3030   не удалось скопировать файл "obj\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\ru\Telesyk.SmartTable.Localization.resources.dll" - файл не найден.
Localization
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    4907

